# Dripping from Soffit Close to the Wall

Tags: windows, leak, siding, soffit, vinyl-siding

When raining, water drips from center of the red circle. My guess is that water gets behind the siding somewhere above and flows to the red circle area behind the siding and soffit. Is the conjecture reasonable? If yes, how to find the entry point efficiently? Thank you.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you able to remove the soffit?

Comment: @Huesmann That's what I plan to do. Remove the soffit and then trace the watermark?

Comment: Yeah, that should be the start of your investigation.